# Python pandas dataframe - any way to set frequency programmatically?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to process CSV files like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("raw_hl.csv", index_col='time', parse_dates = True))
df.head(2)
                    high        low 
time                
2014-01-01 17:00:00 1.376235    1.375945
2014-01-01 17:01:00 1.376005    1.375775
2014-01-01 17:02:00 1.375795    1.375445
2014-01-01 17:07:00 NaN         NaN 
...
2014-01-01 17:49:00 1.375645    1.375445

type(df.index)
pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex
```

But these don't automatically have a frequency:

```
print df.index.freq
None
```

In case they have differing frequencies, it would be handy to be able to set one automatically. The simplest way would be to compare the first two rows:

```
tdelta = df.index[1] - df.index[0]
tdelta
datetime.timedelta(0, 60)
```

So far so good, but setting frequency directly to this timedelta fails:

```
df.index.freq = tdelta
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-3f24abacf9de> in <module>()
----> 1 df.index.freq = tdelta

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Is there a way (ideally relatively painless!) to do this?

ANSWER: Pandas has given the dataframe has a index.inferred_freq attribute - perhaps to avoid overwriting a user defined frequency.
df.index.inferred_freq = 'T'

So it just seems to be a matter of using this instead of df.index.freq. Thanks to Jeff, who also provides more details below :)

Comment: by default since you only have 2 elements frequency is not computed, nor necessary. If you have at least 3 then it will be inferred.

Comment: In fact the data I'm using has several thousand rows; so this doesn't seem to be it. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: It won't do this unless its necessary (as its a tiny bit computational), e.g. when you resample. You can see what it is, by doing ``df.index.inferred_freq``. However if it is STILL ``None``. then it is not a regular frequency. You might want to reindex to make it one.

Comment: Thanks! I get: df.index.inferred_freq = T, which I seem to remember means a 1 minute offset. I'll edit this in above.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you *have* a regular frequency it will be reported when you look at `df.index.freq`

```
In [20]: df = DataFrame({'A' : np.arange(5)},index=pd.date_range('20130101 09:00:00',freq='3T',periods=5))

In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
                     A
2013-01-01 09:00:00  0
2013-01-01 09:03:00  1
2013-01-01 09:06:00  2
2013-01-01 09:09:00  3
2013-01-01 09:12:00  4

In [22]: df.index.freq
Out[22]: <3 * Minutes>
```

Have an *irregular* frequency will return `None`

```
In [23]: df.index = df.index[0:2].tolist() + [Timestamp('20130101 09:05:00')] + df.index[-2:].tolist()

In [24]: df
Out[24]: 
                     A
2013-01-01 09:00:00  0
2013-01-01 09:03:00  1
2013-01-01 09:05:00  2
2013-01-01 09:09:00  3
2013-01-01 09:12:00  4

In [25]: df.index.freq
```

You can recover a regular frequency by doing this. Downsampling to a lower freq (where you don't have overlapping values), forward filling, then reindexing to the desired frequency and end-points).

```
In [31]: df.resample('T').ffill().reindex(pd.date_range(df.index[0],df.index[-1],freq='3T'))
Out[31]: 
                     A
2013-01-01 09:00:00  0
2013-01-01 09:03:00  1
2013-01-01 09:06:00  2
2013-01-01 09:09:00  3
2013-01-01 09:12:00  4
```

Comment: Jeff, super useful many thanks. Maybe you meant "upsampling to a higher freq" ( increasing the number of samples) instead of "Downsampling to a lower freq" ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, loading data from CSV with a regular frequency, `freq` is `None` but there is a `inferred_freq` attribute with the intended value, as the OP pointed out.

With the current version of pandas (1.3.4), assignment to `freq` seems to work, so a solution would be:

```
df.index.freq = df.index.inferred_freq
```

An alternative could be to create a new index

```
df.index = pd.date_range(
    start=df.index[0],
    periods=len(df),
    freq=df.index.inferred_freq
)
```