# Resampling pandas time series to a predefined grid

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Suppose I Have a Weekly time series built like this:

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='D')
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
weekly = ts.resample('W').mean()
```

and you have another series daily spaced, which you would like to also agregate weekly but in such a way that it matches the first one.

```
rng2 = pd.date_range('17/1/2011', periods=72, freq='D')
ts2 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng2)), index=rng2)
```

Note that the second series does not start on the same date, so simply resampling `ts2` it would make the two weekly series misalign. It would be nice if resample could receive a detetime index to resample to, but AFAICT this not possible.

How would you do this?

Comment: In your example you should change the index of ts2 to rng2 (can't edit myself as it would be shorter than 6 characters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@FLab answer is best imo, if you want the exact same index on both series you could also do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='D')
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
weekly = ts.resample('W').mean()

rng2 = pd.date_range('17/1/2011', periods=72, freq='D')
ts2 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng2)), index=rng2)

ts2.reindex(ts.index).resample('W').mean()

Out[14]: 
2011-01-02         NaN
2011-01-09         NaN
2011-01-16         NaN
2011-01-23   -0.073253
2011-01-30   -0.065030
2011-02-06   -0.037297
2011-02-13    0.101782
2011-02-20   -0.386027
2011-02-27    0.131906
2011-03-06    0.107101
2011-03-13   -0.030496
Freq: W-SUN, dtype: float64
```

if you don't have access to the prior index, just use @FLab method such has:

```
ts.resample('W-SUN').mean()
ts2.resample('W-SUN').mean()
```

you can pass multiple arg here :

```
Alias   Description
W-SUN   weekly frequency (sundays). Same as ‘W’
W-MON   weekly frequency (mondays)
W-TUE   weekly frequency (tuesdays)
W-WED   weekly frequency (wednesdays)
W-THU   weekly frequency (thursdays)
W-FRI   weekly frequency (fridays)
W-SAT   weekly frequency (saturdays)
```

Comment: Steven, assume you have no acces to the original ts, just the original weekly series.

Comment: I just tested. It works if you reindex directly with weekly.index.

Comment: Watch out: if you reindex directly with weekly.index the code still runs, but you would get different (wrong) results.

ts2.reindex(weekly.index) contains observations of ts2 that happens on Sunday. So when you resample, you are not taking an average, but simply keeping Sunday's values.

Comment: if you don't have access to the  prior index, just use resample and specify which day to start with : ts.resample('W-SUN').mean()

Answer (score 2):

When resampling to weekly, you can also specify on which day your week is starting: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets.

Hence you can do:

```
ts2_resamples = ts2.resample(weekly.index.freq).mean()
```

Comment: This way works if the weekly series has been created by aggregation. If it hasn't, the freq attribute of the index does not exist.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I thought that was the assumption of the example.
If in your code you rely on the frequency of a series, I think it is better to enforce it explicitly. In other words even if you were reading from csv a weekly series starting on Sunday, I think I would check if the frequency is recognised by pandas, otherwise I would set myself explicitly.

Comment: You might also be interested in this question, if you need to set a specific frequency:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607974/python-pandas-dataframe-any-way-to-set-frequency-programmatically