# Python Dataframe.resample() deletes time from datetimeindex

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, time-series

For some reason, resampling to `24H` or `1D` chops time from `DateTimeIndex`.

i'm using
python: 3.5.3 / conda
numpy: 1.11.3
pandas: 0.20.2

```
df = pd.read_csv(inFile, parse_dates=True)

print(df.head())
df = df.resample("1D").agg({'open':'first','high':'max','low' :'min','close': 'last','volume': 'sum'}).dropna()

print(df.head()
```

First print statement

[image]

Second

[image]

Comment: What was your expectation? It seemed pretty normal to me.

Comment: If you check the indexes, you'll see that it has a freq attribute that changes from None to 'D' when you resample.  it is sort of explained in this answer from over 2 years ago and doesn't look like it can be changed (at least as of 2 years ago)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607974/python-pandas-dataframe-any-way-to-set-frequency-programmatically  In any event, note that it's a display issue, the index type has not changed.

Comment: @ayhan - i want to see time printed as well (00:00:00)

Comment: @JohnE: yes, the index type is correct. But when I run strptime on it, it complains: ValueError: time data '2017-05-30' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: But the max, min, or last didn't occur at 00:00? Doing an aggregation you are going from hourly to daily data.  I would understand if you were only getting the first values but for the others that index would be wrong in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks @JohnE, but that would lead to unforeseem time lags

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index.format(formatter=lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
```